# How to compute $\left ( \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right )_{x\rightarrow 0}$?

Tags: partial-derivative

I'm afraid this is a stupid question with an obvious response, but I don't trust myself and would love your help.

How do I compute this:$$\left ( \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right )_{x\rightarrow 0}$$

Would I have to compute the partial derivative of y wrt x and then compute the limit of this expression as x approaches zero? would I just plug in zero for x? Or is this not even close to how to do it? :/

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ related? If not, it is $0$.

Comment: They are related

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute the partial derivative of y wrt x and then compute the limit of this expression as x approaches zero